# Calculate distance between 2 objects by calculating the mid points

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing

I have labelled image objects with their respective height ,width and coordinates of bounding box around them in pixels. I have calculated the mid point of both the bounding box.how to compare the mid point of both the objects and calculate distance between two them.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the 2D distance within the image? In this case, find the [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance):

```
const double dx = a.x - b.x;
const double dy = a.y - b.y;
const double distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
```

where `a` and `b` are your mid-points.

Comment: i have variable called midpoints which contains the cordinates x and y. how shall i compare two objetcs at once?

Comment: In the above code, replace `a` and `b` with your midpoint variables.